# MySQL - Update table1 from a condition and a max(value) from other table2

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I have a little issue in MySQL. 
Here are two tables:

table1: id, value1, value2

table2: id, table1_fk

In the table1, there is some duplicate row where the value1 and value2 are the same (but with a different id).

I would like to delete duplicates rows from table1 and keeping the one with the highest id.

But first i need to link the row from table2 which where linked to the duplicate (with lowest id) before deleting them.

Thanks a lot for helping me.

So far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW duplicateTable1 as
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT t2.id
              FROM table1 t2
              WHERE t1.value1= t2.value1
              AND t1.value2= t2.value2
              AND t1.id <> t3.id)
order by value1, value2;


CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW duplicatetable2 as
SELECT *
FROM table2 t2
WHERE t2.table_fk in (
SELECT d.id
FROM duplicateTable1 d
);

Update table2 t2
Set t2.subscription_fk = (
SELECT Max(d.id)
FROM duplicateTable1 d
where d.id=t2.subscription_fk
GROUP BY d.value1, d.value2
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp 
    SELECT MAX(id) as id, value1, value2
    FROM table1 GROUP BY value1, value2;

UPDATE table2
JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.id = table1_fk
JOIN tmp t ON t.value1 = t11.value1 AND t.value2 = t11.value2
SET table2.table1_fk = t.id;

DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM tmp);
```